# Vimeo API "alphabetical" sort does not work for search videos

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Vimeo API "alphabetical" sort does is not working for the search videos api. For example https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=mahout&sort=alphabetical&direction=asc. The results are not sorted by title or description.

Comment: No answer, but I can confirm it does not appear to be working.

Comment: Probably a bug, I'll take a look. For future reference, bugs are best reported via https://vimeo.com/help/contact. You can learn more about the Vimeo API support channels through https://developer.vimeo.com/help

Comment: I believe this is now fixed. Let me know!

Comment: I tested my call again and the sort with alphabetical still does not seem to work. Do these changes get pushed immediately.